# Problems with Cytoscape on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: cytoscape

I am using Ubuntu 19.10 and am having problems launching Cytoscape despite having Java 11:

Error message:

```
Your current $PATH: 

/home/kimani/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/ncbi/sra-tools/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/cd-hit:/usr/lib/cd-hit 

Checking $JAVA_HOME 

Error: $JAVA HOME is not set

If you don't have Java yet, please download JDK from Oracle web site:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Don't forget to select correct version. 
Your machine type is: x86_64

Checking Connection to Cytoscape App Store 

 - Checking connection to Cytoscape App Store...

apps.cytoscape.org has address 52.34.133.210

 - Result: 4 packets transmitted, 0 received, +4 errors, 100% packet loss, time 3002ms
Error: Seems connection to App Store is unstable.

traceroute result:
traceroute to apps.cytoscape.org (52.34.133.210), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  _gateway (10.10.10.254) 0.992 ms  1.492 ms 2.039 ms
 2  10.40.0.1 (10.40.0.1) 3.642 ms  3.701 ms 3.680 ms
 3  172.16.180.34(172.16.180.34)  8.137 ms  8.459 ms 8.375 ms
 4  172.16.180.186(172.16.180.186)  17.366 ms 17.699 ms  17.686 ms
 5  172.16.180.185(172.16.180.185)  18.061 ms 18.037 ms  18.019 ms
```

Image for better reading:

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of error messages - if the link goes stale essential information goes missing from this post. Also people facing the same problem will not be able to find this post and answers because text in images is not indexed by search engines.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you can try.  First, do a **which java**
in your shell to make sure there is a path to your installed Java 11.  Second, if you see an installed Java on your path, try doing a **java -version** to make sure the correct Java shows up.  Finally, could you try running Cytoscape from the shell to catch the output errors.  By default that would be /opt/Cytoscape_v3.8.0/cytoscape.sh.

Thanks!

-- scooter